# How to install specific version of libxml2 on Alpine linux without downgrade of whole alpine to v3.1?

Tags: alpine-linux

Latest available version of libxml2 is [2.9.4-r2](https://pkgs.alpinelinux.org/packages?name=libxml2) (alpine linux v3.5). But due to [regression bug](https://github.com/shlomif/libxml2-2.9.4-reader-schema-regression) I need to install 2.9.3 or earlier. How can I do this without downgrade of whole alpine to v3.1?

I'm trying to use `apk add` command like in [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/1055060/how-to-install-a-specific-package-version-in-alpine), but getting an error:

```
/ # apk add 'libxml2<2.9.4'
ERROR: unsatisfiable constraints:
  libxml2-2.9.4-r2:
    breaks: world[libxml2<2.9.4]
```

If I add `-r0` suffix to version - same result.

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this:

```
# echo 'http://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/v3.1/main' >> 
/etc/apk/repositories

# apk add 'libxml2==2.9.2-r2'
```