# Installl a specific package version of Apache in Alpine 3.4

Tags: alpine-linux

I would like to install Apache 2.4.23-r1 for my development. However, in Alpine Linux the package has been upgraded to 2.4.25-r1.

[Package Repository](https://pkgs.alpinelinux.org/packages?name=apache2&branch=&repo=&arch=&maintainer=) to see the history of the package.

```
/ # apk add apache2=="2.4.23-r1"
ERROR: unsatisfiable constraints:
  apache2-2.4.25-r0:
    breaks: world[apache2=2.4.23-r1]
```

How would I be able to install a specific version of Apache?

Comment: As it is a minor version change, is there any real need to get that specific version? You could always build it on your own. Have a look at [How to install a specific package version in Alpine?](https://superuser.com/questions/1055060/how-to-install-a-specific-package-version-in-alpine). The [official wiki](https://wiki.alpinelinux.org/wiki/Alpine_Linux_package_management#Holding_a_specific_package_back) has the same instruction. It doesn't look like you will be able to just grab an older version.

Comment: Yes, I need to have the specific version to test particular script. I try to download the source code try to build it, seem like alpine does not have make command...

Comment: It does. You will have to install the appropriate packages though. [What is the alpine equivalent to build-essential? #24](https://github.com/gliderlabs/docker-alpine/issues/24). But if you don't know how to figure that out, you might not want to build it yourself.

Comment: ok, thanks so there is no easy way to get the old version of the particular software...